# How to find sightseeing places around the driving road Stockholm-Trondheim with a car? Any iPhone application to investigate the area?

Tags: sightseeing, automobiles, sweden, norway

We are going to drive a cultural exchange trip with BEST Helsinki organisation from Finland and this is our road:

[image]

We are trying to find out some sightseeing around the area. We are new on this area and we would like to visit some beautiful places such as world natural heritage places and culturally important places.

**How can I find sightseeing places around the example trip? Is there some kind of iPhone application to find them? Any good climbing places or beautiful places to eat?**

Answer (score 2):

You're looking for a travel guide. I hear Lonely Planet is popular, and they [have apps too](http://www.lonelyplanet.com/apps-and-ebooks/apps/). [Tripwolf](http://www.tripwolf.com/) and [Triposo](http://www.triposo.com/) are well-rated app-centric travel guides. These will certainly cover  world natural heritage places, culturally important places and places to eat as well as you'll be able to find anywhere.

Climbing, however, is a special interest that general travel guides will cover only superficially. Fortunately, there is a dedicated [Climbing in Sweden](https://itunes.apple.com/app/id330942901) app.

Comment: Wow thank you +1 for the suggestions, takes some time to research them!